# Bulk insert rowterminator issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have this csv named test.csv with the content below

```
1,"test user",,,4075619900,example@example.com,"Aldelo for Restaurants","this is my deal",,"location4"
2,"joe johnson",,"32 bit",445555519,antle@gmail.com,"Restaurant Pro Express","smoe one is watching u",,"some location"
```

Here is my SQL FILE to do the BULK insert

```
USE somedb
GO

CREATE TABLE CSVTemp
(id INT,
name VARCHAR(255),
department VARCHAR(255),
architecture VARCHAR(255),
phone VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
download VARCHAR(255),
comments TEXT,
company VARCHAR(255),
location VARCHAR(255))
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTemp
FROM 'c:\test\test.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(124)+''+CHAR(10)+'''
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTemp
GO
```

but whats happening is its only inserting one record and all the info from the second record is getting inserted in the location field on the first record

```
  id,name,department,architecture,phone,email,download,comments,company,location
  1,"test user",NULL,NULL,4075619900,example@example.com,"Aldelo for Restaurants","this is my deal",NULL,"""location4""2,""joe johnson"",,""32 bit"",445555519,antle@gmail.com,""Restaurant Pro Express"",""smoe one is watching u"",,""some location"""
```

I assume the problem is the `ROWTERMINATOR` but i tried all these

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'
```

and all the same results ...any ideas on how to FIX this

I am creating the csv like [this](http://pastie.org/2526717) via PHP

Comment: Did you try `\n\r`? Where did the CSV file come from? Is it possible there is some non-printing character at the end of the line?

Comment: i am generating it via php on the server ...i will update my question

Comment: Maybe show the PHP you are using to generate the CR+LF.

Comment: I will try that now and let you know...I updated my question with my php that i used to generate this csv

Comment: I did...its in my question with a link http://pastie.org/2526717

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting to see actual code. What is fputcsv? If that is a built-in PHP method, your SQL Server audience is unlikely to be aware of it.

Comment: Also, you're using PHP to update MySQL and create a flat file that you turn around and bulk insert into SQL Server. Why not have MySQL communicate directly with SQL Server, and take out all these middle men?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3409/discussion-between-tamer-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: Try with consistent quotation fputcsv($fp,$row,',','"')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think problem is that your csv file uses `\n` as EOL (unix way). BULK INSERT in SQL Server is "smart" and even if you specify `ROWTERMINATOR` as `\n`, which in theory should resolve your problem, it prepends it with `\r` so you end up with `\r\n` as row terminator.

Try using `ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A'`. In this case SQL Server doesn't perform any magic tricks and just uses the value you've set as row terminator.
Works for me. :)

Comment: You can use special format to mark code. More info in the markdown help. Looks like a nice answer for a first one.

Comment: If only I had more than one upvote to give...Thanks Przemek Ptasznik

Comment: I spent a few hours on this issue! You saved my day. Thank you! What a stupid "smart" feature!

Answer (score 1):

> CHAR(124) is | and CHAR(10) is \n

You probably need `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` as Row Terminator

http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php